# How to add xml:lang using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way to display xml:lang in an XML that you are generating from an xslt

I currently have XSLT:

```
<Asset
uriId="{$uriIdProvider}/Title/"
xsi:type="title:TitleType">
    <xsl:element name="title:LocalizableTitle" xml:lang="en"> 
</xsl:element>
```

When I build my xslt I have the XML output:

```
<Asset uriId="indemand.com/Title/" xsi:type="title:TitleType">
   <title:LocalizableTitle>
```

Where you can see the xml:lang="en" is not displayed, I would like to find a way to also include this in my final XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `<xsl:attribute>` :

```
<xsl:element name="title:LocalizableTitle"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="xml:lang">en</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: thankyou, however now I am getting an output that looks like this:     <title:LocalizableTitle xp_0:lang="en" xmlns:xp_0="xml">

Comment: My xsl is rusty :/ . Try removing the namespace and adding it to the name (name="xml:lang"). Also, see Tim C answer if what you want is a static element name.

Comment: removing the namespace worked for me, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are just creating a static element name, you don't actually need to use `xsl:element` here. You could also write it like this, which would ensure the attribute is displayed too.

```
<title:LocalizableTitle xml:lang="en">
</title:LocalizableTitle>
```